# XML Layout changes does not reflecting after deploy on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio Artic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

XML layout changes do not reflecting after run onto Android Phone / Emulator. Sometimes it's work after a clean project then running on the device. To resolve this issue I tried the following methods but even after that, it didn't work.

1. In the "Edit Configurations" setting unchecked following option

   a) "Allow parallel run" (from General Tab)

   b) "Skip installation if APK has not changed" (from Miscellaneous Tab)
2. In "gradle.properties" made following setting as false

   a) org.gradle.caching = false

   b) org.gradle.parallel = false

3. clone new project
4. Tried on different PC

I referred following StackOverflow posted a question as well:
[Android Studio runs old code BUT JUST SOMETIMES. It is fricking annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66371077/android-studio-runs-old-code-but-just-sometimes-it-is-fricking-annoying)

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Any solution for the same? I try to invalidate/cache, still not good. It only happens after I add new view to the layout. If a remove all new layouts then it works fine.

Comment: Any luck? I'm still struggling, even reported it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202864579

Comment: No :(, Even I've to clean build before every run